# Cache Issues with Nuxt3 in Dev

Tags: vue.js, caching, nuxt.js, nuxt3, nitro

i'm having trouble developing with Nuxt3, the problem is that sometimes edits in the code are not visible, it seems that Nitro caches something and I need to restart the server in order to see the updates. The most effective example is when I `console.log` something, then i remove the line, but the log still get printed after I reload the page. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can know the caching behavior by checking/adding new rules in your `nuxt.config.ts`'s `routeRules`. See [nuxt 3 rendering](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering#hybrid-rendering).

Also, a simple trick is to manually delete the cached route in `.nuxt/cache/nitro/routes/_/<route>.json`.